# TinyMCE4 CTRL + Rightclick to open browser's default context menu

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I would like to be able to open default context menu of my browser on some defined action (in my case ctrl + rightclick) instead of TinyMCE's standard context menu.

The case is I'm using browser's spell checking and I want to be able to chose a correction from proposed words. At the moment I use a temporary which is disabling the context menu of TinyMCE, but I would like it to work like normal, but with CTRL + rightclick to open normal browser's context menu.

Do you have any hints how to do that? I couldn't find anything in standard tinymce specifications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there is a better way to do it, but I managed to solve my problem. I edited contextmenu plugin. In development version I just added this stuff to the function which handles the `oncontextmenu` event:

```
editor.on('contextmenu', function(e) {  
        if (e.ctrlKey) {
            return;
        } else {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
```

In `plugin.min.js` file I changed the `e.on(...)` to:

```
(...) e.on("contextmenu",function(n){var i;if(n.ctrlKey){return;}else{n.preventDefault();}if(i=e.settings.contextmenu|| (...)
```